# How to get different data from the same table with months as parameters?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table in Oracle where a price for an article and a date are included but I need the price of the article from the last month and the current month to see the difference.

What I need is to pass the last month as paremeter and get data

Example:

```
+---------+-------+------------+
| article | price | date       |
+---------+-------+------------+
| cup     | 3.5   | 02/06/2018 |
+---------+-------+------------+
| cup     | 3.7   | 04/07/2018 | 
+---------+-------+------------+
| cup     | 3.8   | 04/08/2018 | 
+---------+-------+------------+
```

Expected:

Selected month: 07

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+
| article | current_price|current_month|last_price|last_mont |
+---------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+
| cup     |      3.7     |  07/2018    | 3.5      |  06/2018 |
+---------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following SQL statement :

```
select article, 
       max(decode(to_char("date",'mm/yyyy'),to_char(sysdate,'mm/yyyy'),nvl(price,0)))
       as current_price,
       to_char(sysdate,'mm/yyyy') as current_month,
       max(decode(to_char("date",'mm/yyyy'),to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1),'mm/yyyy'),
                                                                nvl(price,0)))
       as last_price,
       to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1),'mm/yyyy') as last_month
  from articles 
 where article = 'cup'
group by article;

ARTICLE CURRENT_PRICE   CURRENT_MONTH   LAST_PRICE  LAST_MONTH
  cup       3,70           07/2018         3,50       06/2018
```

*assuming sysdate(current date) between `01/07/2018 - 31/07/2018` (format `dd/mm/yyyy`)*

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/ELW66438)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user is specifying a *date*, then the following gets the last two dates and prices through that date:

```
select article_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then price end) as current_price,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then date end) as current_date,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then price end) as last_price,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then price end) as last_date
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by article_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from examples e
      where e.date <= :date
     ) e
group by article_id;
```